# How to access property in foreach List

Tags: c#, list

I was create the object with has a few property inside. So with this object, I will add the value after query from database.

After that, I need to do grouping and sum. So I will do like this :

```
var after_grouping = from t in list_item
                    group t by new {t.category_subcategory,t.item} into g
                    select new {
                        no = g.Key,
                        price = g.Sum(a=>a.price),
                        quantity = g.Sum(a=>a.quantity)

                    };
```

Then I need to add the value from "after_grouping" to the **new object class**. So I will do foreach in variable **"after_grouping"**.

```
 foreach(PropertyInfo eachRow in after_grouping.GetType().GetProperties())
        { 
            string cat_sub = "";
            string item_name = "";
            decimal price = 0;
            decimal quantity = 0;
            decimal total = 0;  
            //Access the object here

            listAfterCopy.Add(new SelectedItemOnPoCopy(cat_sub, item_name, price, quantity, total));

        }
```

My question is, **how can I access** the property was I create in variable "after_grouping"?

If do you have any better suggestion, please let me know.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetType` and `GetProperties` in your looping construct? By doing so you're looping over the reflected properties of the anonymous type you created earlier, not instances of that type in a collection.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot , Sorry my bad, I think that is correct way before this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need reflection to do that. You can access anonymous type properties the same way you'd do with you own custom class:

```
foreach(var item in after_grouping)
{ 
    listAfterCopy.Add(
        new SelectedItemOnPoCopy(
            item.no.category_subcategory,
            item.no.item,
            item.price,
            item.quantity
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks man. Sorry I do not quite understand before this. I think still need to do reflection to access the property.